# У windows 10 есть защита от Spectre?

Tags: windows, безопасность

Утилита [InSpectre](https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm) выдаёт ошибку: **System is Spectre protected: NO!**

> This system's hardware has not been updated with new features required
>   to allow its operating system to protect against the Spectre
>   vulnerabilities and/or to minimize their impact upon the system's
>   performance. (Protection from the Meltdown vulnerability does not
>   require BIOS or processor updates.)

Т.е. насколько я понял для защиты от Spectre нужно обновлять биос? И что означает "processor updates"?

Comment: Spectre - это определенный тип атак на приложения,  запускающие внутри себя сторонний код (например,  на браузеры). Это не уязвимость в windows,  и защиту от нее нельзя "включить", так что кто его знает что там утилита напроверяла.

Comment: @PashaPash Некорректно. Это действительно _определенный тип атак_ на ЛЮБЫЕ приложения, НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО запускающие сторонний код. Под любыми определяется тип приложений security_level 1 и 2, т.е. привилегированные и пользовательские

Comment: @ViktorTomilov вы точно не путаете Spectre и Meltdown?

Comment: @PashaPash экспериментальную защиту от Spectre на некоторых новых процессорах можно включить при загрузке системы (что приведет к замедлению работы, вылетам в BSOD и паникам ядра)

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну это как-то совсем сурово - чинить валидный паттерн работы процессора хардварной защитой. Тем более что из затронутых приложений, пока, только браузеры

Comment: @ОлегУрукхаев вы просто неправильно прочитали сообщение программы. Там написано, что для фикса Meltdown не нужно обновлять биос или процессор. Об обновлении биоса для исправления Spectre там вообще ничего нет :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov На мой взгляд, не путаю.

Answer (score -2):

Фактически, Spectre, если не вдаваться в подробности, - следствие погони за производительностью, взятой на вооружение Intel с десяток лет назад, и вынужденно поддержанной другими вендорами (правда, несколько по-разному, как следствие, и проблемы в защите выглядят по-разному).

Полноценных заплаток, насколько мне известно, на данный момент (ориентируюсь на 26 февраля, новее данных у меня нет) не существует.
Насколько я понимаю, возможна защита от него и без обновления BIOS, но это маловероятно. Скорее всего, полноценная защита будет включать в себя:

1. Обновление BIOS + поддерживаемые BIOS обновления микрокода
2. Обновление микрокода процессора для ОС (т.е. обновление загружаемых микропрограмм процеcсора для любых ОС, загружаемых параллельно/предварительно с загрузкой ядра - это, фактически, и есть "processor updates").
3. Возможная (скорее, вероятная для ряда библиотек) рекомпиляция библиотек/программ
4. Потенциальное снижение производительности (в зависимости от производителя/линейки процессоров)

Comment: Вы путаете Spectre и Meltdown. Spectre (не meltdown!) - не баг, не ошибка и не проблема. это вполне задокументированный способ работы процессора. Его нельзя починить обновлениями BIOS, нельзя починить микрокодом, и "исправления" для него не бьют по производительности (по крайней мере нет гарантированного фикса который может взять и починить Spectre раз и навсегда)

Comment: Т.е. на данный момент Spectre проявился как баг в генераторе нативного кода из JS в хроме. И чинится он исправлением хрома, и только им.

Comment: @PashaPash Нет, в данном контексте, не путаю. Исправление возможно, но только как комплексное решение проблемы. К примеру, проблему в блоке TLB можно устранить только с уровня 0, т.е. из ядра: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INVLPG.html  Т.е., в итоге, решение для "старых" процессоров будет найдено, в итоге, но как комплексное, и с обязательным падением производительности

Comment: @PashaPash Логично, для каждой отдельно взятой программы баг (а не документированный способ, разве можно документировать уязвимость?  Это что-то новое)  можно устранить перекомпиляцией кода отдельно взятой программы с добавлением команд управления контролем кэша процессора. Можно пробовать применять подобный подход и на уровне ОС (Retpoline Patch), но падение производительности гарантированно. На последнем вебинаре Google вроде бы утверждал, что падение составит "всего" 3-7%, но как-то не верится

Comment: @ViktorTomilov а какое отношение проблема с кешем TLB имеет к Spectre?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это - как вариант промежуточного решения: сброс значений TLB. Не уверен в 100%ной полноценности такого варианта.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov зато я уверен в полноценности этого варианта аж на целых 0%

Comment: Всё очень сложно...